# Switch docker daemon from windows to linux in windows virtual environment

Tags: linux, windows, docker, github, github-actions

I have created a GitHub actions pipeline for one of my .net projects. The catch is that it is using both .net framework and .net core, so the build and publish only happens in a windows environment and the published data is copied into a Linux container and deployed.

I need to be able to switch the docker daemon from "windows" containers to "linux" containers in a windows GitHub virtual environment but it doesn't seem to be able to find the `DockerCli.exe` file even though docker is installed properly.

Is there a docker command or any other way by which this switch can be done?
Because most of the PowerShell commands don't seem to be executing.